# Choose options via url

Tags: posts, customization, admin, urls

I wonder if it's possible to preselect options when creating new post via url.
My goal is to bookmark links when i want to create post with specific options such as category and not to have to select them each time.

Thanks

Comment: You want to pass the options to be selected via url?

Comment: Yes ! One click in my bookmarks and don't have to worry about which template, category etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think this `Custom Field Template` plugin will help you. [Plugin site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/).
Don't worry about Chinese screenshots. If you set at least one Custom Field Template for one category, when creating post and check that category additional options will appear.